# Is there any community hosted distributed cloud solution?

Tags: docker, cloud, kubernetes, containers, docker-swarm

I got this idea of a distributed cloud solution. I am thinking like a Docker Swarm or Kubernetes solution where you can host a server anywhere you want, and then join it to the community cloud. After you contribute with your hardware you are allowed to host your containers to the cloud. Of course the performance you get needs to be dependent on how much you contribute.

The problems I can see with this solution is mainly security. Many people do not want their services to run on a server that someone unknown has control of. The solution to this would be that no owner of a server in the cluster can see exactly what runs on his server, and I guess this can be complicated.

So my question is, does any similar solution to this already exist? If not, is there a good reason why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a reason why it doesn't exist. Security, availability, durability, latency etc etc.

How can I own the server, join to the cluster and not have permission to access my own node? How can cloud prevent it? It can't.

Who will be in control of masters? How the `open` quorum will work? If anyone can add a master to the cluster then it's basically dead in the water.

You could attack the cluster from inside (recent kubernetes dnsmasq flaw), spam traffic, mingle traffic, remove files (someone schedule database on your node no problem copy and delete it), intentionally or even not intentionally.

There are just too many possible flaws in `open cluster` and none of the solution was created to handle them because then they would be over engineered.

Comment: My idea is that the organisation is in control of the masters, people will only have the ability to add minion/workers/nodes. Also I understand that this can not be built in to Kubernetes or Docker Swarm, but I was thinking of something that is using it in the background.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. I even don't know where to start...
I'm not saying technology isn't capable of doing it. Kubernetes can do it and docker swarm as well. This is not a problem here. Start from reading this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/master-node-communication/ maybe this will enlighten you

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say, more than that you do not believe in the idea. I do know how Kubernetes works (at least on a high level) but thanks for the link. Could you be more specific of what's so wrong?